# wso2 identity server : generating keys throwing error :Please pick another role name

Tags: server, wso2, identity, role, wso2-identity-server

While generating keys inside the store after login to store am getting this error. What could be the issue am new to wso2 identity server?

I just followed all the steps given in the below link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.1

```
[2016-02-17 14:46:33,866] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl} -  
Error occurred while creating the application, gangadhar_DefaultApplication_SANDBOX
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementException: Error while creating application
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationMgtUtil.createAppRole(ApplicationMgtUtil.java:145)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.createApplication(ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.java:112)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.createOAuthApplication(APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.java:167)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Role name: gangadhar_DefaultApplication_SANDBOX_DefaultApplication_SANDBOX in the system. Please pick another role name.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doAddInternalRole(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2478)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addRole(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addRole(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3453)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationMgtUtil.createAppRole(ApplicationMgtUtil.java:142)
        ... 47 more
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you resolve it, and do you mind posting your solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem. Just in case somebody's gonna need the solution, it is very simple. Log in to the IS Console (Carbon), click on List of Service Providers and delete `admin_DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION` and `admin_DefaultApplication_SANDBOX`. Log back in to the APIM Console (Carbon) and re-generate your tokens. It will recreate these items. Cheers.